# JavaScript pressing a button to show text not working with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I got this code for JavaScript and I have an error; when I use more than one read more button, it shows the first text only. If I used 3 buttons and I press on any of these 3, only the first one would show the first one in HTML and the bottom ones are not even there.

The only solution I tried is to change the variable names and the function names for this to work and used same function again and again but I want one function for all the read more buttons.

I'm not allowed to use jQuery for this college project so if you could help me in JavaScript thank you.

The button code:

```
<span id="dots1">...</span>
<span style="display: none;" id="more1">The text I want to be on read more</span>
</p></p>
<button onclick="Show1()" class="btn" id="myBtn1">Read more</button>
```

and this is the JavaScript code:

```
function Show() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
  
  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The current state of the question is unclear. Could you clarify what your intention is for having multiple buttons, and what doesn't work about that? Is the problem that you want to reuse the `Show` function to work for multiple "Read more" buttons?

Comment: My problem is that if I apply this to more than one button( of course all the buttons have same ids classes) it would only work on the first button according to html order it's like it will only activate the first button and the rest if you pressed them it would activate the first as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you need is to re-use the same function for any amount of buttons on your page, to show and hide the text.

To do this, you would first group up each set of `button` and `span` elements, e.g. putting a `div`  around them. This step is important, since it allows us to easily refer to other elements in the same group.

Then, you can add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on all the buttons, listening on the `click` event (this is very similar to the `onclick` attribute you currently use - but is very much preferred). The handler for this can more or less be your existing function -- slightly adapted though. Instead of selecting the `span` elements by their `id`, you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) on the `parentElement` of the `button` -- this being the `div` we added earlier. This would find two such `spans` -- `dots` and `moreText`. The rest of the function would remain the same.

Here is a working snippet that demonstrates this for two buttons. The JS would still work if you add further buttons as needed.

```js
for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll('.btn')) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const [ dots, moreText ] = Array.from(btn.parentElement.querySelectorAll('span'));
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btn.innerHTML = "Read more";
      moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btn.innerHTML = "Read less";
      moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="dots1">...</span>
  <span style="display: none;" id="more1">The text I want to be on read more</span>
  <p></p>
  <button class="btn" id="myBtn1">Read more</button>
</div>

<div>
  <span id="dots2">...</span>
  <span style="display: none;" id="more2">The text I want to be on read more</span>
  <p></p>
  <button class="btn" id="myBtn2">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it does work perfectly the only thing needs to change is the button location but it's perfect thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think the problem is that you use getElementById and you keep calling the same part of the html with every button.

to solve this you could give every Read More part in your html a different id and call this in your javascript accordingly.

Comment: that's the solution I  tried but it's too long and I want something short like one function should be enough I tried to change it to class but it stopped working at all

Comment: @Al-Meqdad Jabi :Try my solution. See If that is something you were looking for . Peace :)

Comment: If you  put a function for every button it will be long indeed but you can give a parameter in your function and run that function with any of the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You want to kind of toggle the btn text, also show and hide content on btn cliks. I have created it for you :)

Have made basic changes in HTML file. Do pay attention :)

```js
  
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const span2 = document.querySelector(".more2");
btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
  
  if(span2.style.display === "none"){
    span2.style.display = "inline-block";
    btn.textContent = "Read Less";
  }else if(span2.style.display === "inline-block"){
     span2.style.display = "none";
    btn.textContent = "Read More";
  }
});
```

```css
div{
  margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
<span id="dots1">...</span>
<span class="more2" style="display: none;">The text I want to be on read more</span>
  </div>
<button class="btn">Read more</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Al-Miqdad: Let me know if this is the behaviour that you want. If not let me know what you requirement is :) I would love to help you my brother :)

Comment: I tried it and it works for one button but same problem if I apply it to more than one it only works on one button which will be the first according to the html order

Comment: Wait... Do you want more than one button in your application. And whichever is clicked you want to do same kind of toggling which happens here for one button. Right Brother? Let me know what your actual scenario is .. Do you need to generate buttons from Javascript or from you HTML itsefl there will be many buttons :)

Comment: Yes I want more than one button in my website sorry for being unclear about this

Comment: OK! Got it... You want more than 1 button . Cool. Do you want to have these spans with that also ..

Comment: Also, need to know. Do we need to create buttons and spans in Javascript or they will be in the code already present :) –

Comment: Note that in any of the scenarios, I will try it for you. Just tell me which scenario you are trying to work with :)

Comment: I think the buttons are already there in html they are one the site, like I have 6 buttons I want each button to show the text I put in them so I guess I want a toggle that works for all buttons, maybe I'm still being unclear sorry for that but I don't know how to explain more

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226694/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-al-meqdad-jabi).